How to know if a MessageChannel is inbound or outbound channel in spring cloud stream 4.x version onwards?
Prior to 4.x version, based on this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1425, we could check if a message channel instance is DirectWithAttributesChannel and then use Sink.INPUT or Source.OUTPUT to determine if it is outbound type or inbound type.  Sink & Source are removed in newer version. How should we determine it ?
